# Extract between two line numbers in same order

Tags: awk, sed

I have a File 1 with one column:

```
File 1
apple
pineapple
banana
cherry
kiwi
orange
mango
grape
watermelon
```

I need to extract the content of row in same order between two line numbers, separated with tab. For example for line 3 to line 8 the output should be:

```
Output (Forward)    
banana cherry kiwi orange mango grape
```

and for line 7 to line 2 the output should be:

```
Output (reverse)    
mango orange kiwi cherry banana pineapple
```

I know to extract between lines in forward order with [sed](/questions/tagged/sed), but having problem with reverse order.

```
sed '3,8!d'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use

```
sed '2,7!d' file1 | tac
```

`tac` simply repeats what it is given in reverse (linewise).

As for the tab-separated part, there are a number of ways to do this with sed. One of them is

```
sed '2,7!d' | tac | sed '1h; 1!H; $!d; x; s/\n/\t/g'
```

This assembles the full input in the hold buffer, then swaps it into the pattern space and replaces all newlines in it with tabs:

```
1h          # first line: save to hold buffer
1!H         # subsequent lines: append to hold buffer
$!d         # if more input is to read, stop here (don't print anything)
x           # otherwise: swap in assembled lines
s/\n/\t/g   # replace newlines with tabs.
```

You could also consider using `tr` for this step, but the trailing newline makes that not as straightforward as one might think at first.

Alternatively, you can do the whole thing in one go just with sed:

```
sed '2,7 { G; x; }; $!d; x; s/\n$//; s/\n/\t/g' file1
```

This is a little more tricky:

```
2,7 {                  # In lines 2 to 7:
  G                    # Append the hold buffer to the pattern space
                       # this is originally a blank line and later the reverse
                       # of the lines already read
  x                    # then swap it back into the hold buffer
}
$!d                    # If the input has not ended, stop here (print nothing)
x                      # When the whole input is consumed, swap the assembled
                       # reverse lines back in
s/\n$//                # remove the trailing newline
s/\n/\t/g              # then replace the newlines with tabs
```

It's a bit of a toss-up which approach is nicer. The latter is still somewhat sane to do with sed, but the Batman decoder ring property of more complex sed scripts is already showing. Frankly, and it hurts me to say this because I have a soft spot for sed, it's not a bad idea to consider abandoning sed in this instance for longer but more readable alternatives such as `awk`:

```
awk 'NR == 2, NR == 7 { result = $0 sep result; sep = "\t" } END { print result }' file1
```

Comment: I overlooked the *reverse order* requirement on my first read of the question. `tac` is a good approach!

Answer (score 2):

I would do with awk:

```
awk -v from="7" -v to="2" 'BEGIN{rev=from>to;s=rev?to:from;e=rev?from:to}
NR>=s && NR<=e{r[NR]=$0}
NR>e{
    while(from!=to){
        printf "%s\t",r[from]
        rev?--from:++from
    }
print r[from]
exit}' file
```

- with this awk script, you just give `from` and `to` variables. If you gave reversed numbers, it prints rows in that range in reverse. It is also easy to embed it in your shell script, to receive the `from, to` from your shell variables.
- the script will break out after processing the `max(from,to)` line. For example, if your file had 5 million lines, you gave `from:2, to:7` The script just processes till line 7.

Some test with your input:

```
kent$  cat f
apple
pineapple
banana
cherry
kiwi
orange
mango
grape
watermelon

kent$  awk -v from="2" -v to="7" 'BEGIN{rev=from>to;s=rev?to:from;e=rev?from:to}
NR>=s && NR<=e{r[NR]=$0}
NR>e{
        while(from!=to){
                printf "%s\t",r[from]
                rev?--from:++from
        }
print r[from]
exit}' f
pineapple       banana  cherry  kiwi    orange  mango

kent$  awk -v from="7" -v to="2" 'BEGIN{rev=from>to;s=rev?to:from;e=rev?from:to}          
NR>=s && NR<=e{r[NR]=$0}
NR>e{
        while(from!=to){
                printf "%s\t",r[from]
                rev?--from:++from
        }
print r[from]
exit}' f
mango   orange  kiwi    cherry  banana  pineapple
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    OFS="\t"
    if (beg < end) { min=beg; max=end; delta=+1 }
    else           { min=end; max=beg; delta=-1 }
}
NR >= min { a[NR] = $0 }
NR == max {
    for (i=beg; i!=end; i+=delta) {
        printf "%s%s", a[i], OFS
    }
    print a[end]
    exit
}

$ awk -v beg=3 -v end=8 -f tst.awk file
banana  cherry  kiwi    orange  mango   grape

$ awk -v beg=7 -v end=2 -f tst.awk file
mango   orange  kiwi    cherry  banana  pineapple
```

Answer (score 0):

Processing lines in reverse order is a task `sed` is not suited for. Due to it's nature as a *stream* processor, it is designed to process lines in forward order.

I would strongly recommend to use `awk`. While basically even `awk` don't offer the feature to process the input file in reverse order, it offers programming language capabilities to buffer the lines of interest and print them in reverse order once the stop line has been reached:

*script.awk:*

```
BEGIN {
    reverse = 0
    if(start>stop) {
        reverse = 1
        start_ = start
        start = stop
        stop = start_
    }
}

NR>=start && NR<=stop {
    buf[NR]=$0
}

NR==stop{
    if(!reverse) {
        for(i=start;i<=stop;i++) {
            printf "%s ",buf[i]
        }
    } else {
        for(i=stop;i>=start;i--) {
            printf "%s\t",buf[i]
        }
    }
    printf "\n"
    exit(0)
}
```

Call it like this:

```
awk -vstart=4 -vstop=9 -f script.awk input.file
```

or

```
awk -vstart=3 -vstop=8 -f script.awk input.file
```

Instead of `awk`, you can use any other programming language you want.

Comment: it is good to consider exiting when `NR==stop`, however I think you should move codes in `END{}` block into `NR==stop`.  Or there is gonna no output unless the user given `max(start,stop) == lastLine`. The `END{...}` is not necessary actually.

Comment: I don't think your `sed | tac` line will work. You're assembling the line before `tac` gets it, so `tac` has only one line to reverse. `tac` before `sed` would have the problem of picking the lines without knowing how many lines of input there are going to be, so I don't think there's a way around `sed | tac | sed` if `tac` is to be used.

Comment: @Kent `awk` will process the `END` block *even after* the explicit call to `exit()`, the program will work. But, you are right I could refactor it and merge the `NR==stop` and `END` block. (Edited that)

Comment: I see spaces instead of tabs, unlike in the question, but close enough/easy to modify. `tr` will replace the trailing newline with a tab as well, which may or may not be a problem. It's why I put a sed thing there, anyway.

Comment: @Wintermute The `sed` solution will add an additional tab, that's true. However, the general answer should be: "use awk", since `sed` is simply not capable of solving this kind of problem by it's nature: it's a *stream* editor. Probably I should emphasize this more in my answer.

Comment: @hek2mgl Weeeeelll, "not capable" is a tad on the strong side for this claim; see my answer for a pure sed solution. I agree that awk is a sane (perhaps saner) choice for this problem, though.

Comment: @Wintermute Nice one! :) I did not really realized that since I was too busy with changing my own answer back and forth... I upvoted yours already, I wish I could twice!